# Using abstraction with constructor

Tags: java

I am trying to use constructor with abstract classes ,I am able to use values defined in multip class for mul and div abstract method but I want to use value used in constructor addition i.e 24 and 4 when abstract methods add and sub is invoked in main.
Can someone suggest what should I do for same.

Thanks in advance.

```
package repeatPracticeJava;

abstract class addition{
    addition(){
        this.a=24;
        this.b=4;

    }

    int a,b,c;
    String str;
    abstract void add();
    abstract void sub();
    //abstract void mul();
    //abstract void div();
}

abstract class multip extends addition{
    multip(){
        this.a=12;
        this.b=3;
    }

    multip(String str){
        this.str="ajay";
        this.a=100;
        this.b=5;
    }
    abstract void mul();
    abstract void div();    
}

public class abstractprat extends multip{

    @Override
    void mul() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        c=a*b;
        System.out.println(c);
    }

    @Override
    void div() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        c=a/b;
        System.out.println(c);
    }

    @Override
    void add() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        c=a+b;
        System.out.println(c);
    }

    @Override
    void sub() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        c=a-b;
        System.out.println(c);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        abstractprat obj = new abstractprat();

        obj.mul();
        obj.div();
        obj.add();
        obj.sub();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are unable to use the values in abstract class addition because as the constructor of multip class is overwriting the values of variables a and b in it. The constructor hierarchy clearly states that first the constructor of top-most class is called and then the second top-most class is called ex: If C extends B extends A, then the constructor of class A will be called first then constructor of class B and then of class C is called. Hence, in your code the constructor of class addition is intializing them to 24,4 but the constructor of class multip is overwriting them to be 12,3. Hence, the variable values remain 12,3 and it is getting accessed in all the methods of abstractpart class. If you want to access the variable values from class addition then have different variables in class multip and addition. Hope this may solve your problem, I have edited your code which will work according to your requirement specified in your question:

```
abstract class addition{
  int a,b,c;
 addition(){
    this.a=24;
    this.b=4;

}


String str;
abstract void add();
abstract void sub();

}

abstract class multip extends addition{

  int a1,b1,c1;    

   multip(){
    this.a1=12;
    this.b1=3;
}

multip(String str){
    this.str="ajay";
    this.a1=100;
    this.b1=5;
}
abstract void mul();
abstract void div();    
}

 public class abstractpart extends multip{

@Override
void mul() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    c1=a1*b1;
    System.out.println(c1);
}

@Override
void div() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    c1=a1/b1;
    System.out.println(c1);
}

@Override
void add() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    c=a+b;
    System.out.println(c);
}

@Override
void sub() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    c=a-b;
    System.out.println(c);
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    Test2 obj = new Test2();

    obj.mul();
    obj.div();
    obj.add();
    obj.sub();
}

}
```